# How to resolve 'nullptr not declared in this scope' compiling error in Ros_lib blink example and other ros_lib examples Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic?

Tags: arduino, c++, ros-noetic

I am new to ros and I am using virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 and ros neotic in it. I have installed rosserial arduino package step by step from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup).

After this I open ros_lib blink example and it shows the following error:

```
/home/rospc/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:121:45: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
   Publisher * publishers[MAX_PUBLISHERS] = {nullptr};
                                             ^
/home/rospc/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:122:47: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
   Subscriber_ * subscribers[MAX_SUBSCRIBERS] {nullptr};
here is the verbose output
In file included from Blink.pde:7:0:
/home/rospc/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/std_msgs/Empty.h:20:53: warning: override controls (override/final) only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     virtual int serialize(unsigned char *outbuffer) const override
```

And other examples despite of ros_lib examples are successfully compiled and uploaded to the arduino board. And this error message has shown on all ros_lib examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `add_compile_options(-std=c++11)` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` to your `CMakeLists.txt` (assuming you installed an Arduino IDE version with a compiler supporting C++11).
The project [doesn't specify a C++ version](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/gcc7-fixes/rosserial_arduino/arduino-cmake/cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake#L2090), so one of the "latest" [commits](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/commit/a7ac6cd5f55401148a8e8c854d9029f3e815d8e5) destroyed the examples if the `gcc` used doesn't define C++11 or newer as default.

Comment: Forgive me for my late reply as I was busy in other things please tell me where to find my CMakeLists.txt file, as I get the error in arduino ide.

Comment: I've never used the Arduino Environment with ROS but if you don't have a `CMakeLists.txt` in `/home/rospc/sketchbook/` you might try the source installation. But maybe you also just need to change to another compiler supporting C++11 or newer in the [Arduino IDE settings](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/changing-finding-out-the-c-compiler-version/604413/2).